# Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, $\dim(V) = 2$. Prove every $f \in \text{Hom}(V, V)$ is triangularizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. Consider the following problem.

> Suppose $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$ and $\dim(V) = 2$. Show that every $f \in
>     \text{Hom}(V, V)$ is triangularizable. This is, that there is a basis of $V$
> such that the matrix representation of $f$ is upper triangular.

This problem was given to me in a practice sheet regarding eigenvalues and eigenvectors. However, I do not see how these two topics are relevant to the problem. Since $V$ is a two-dimensional space over $\mathbb{C}$, any $f \in \text{Hom}(V, V)$ has a
matrix representation

\begin{align*}
|f|_{CC} = \begin{pmatrix}
    x & w \\ 
    y & z
\end{pmatrix} 
.\end{align*}

with $(x, y) = f(1, 0), (w, z) = f(0, 1)$. It seems then that we are set out to find a basis $B$ of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(1, 0) = (\lambda, 0)_B$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. That would suffice to make the representation of $f$ under $B$ upper-triangular (the $a_{21}$ entry would be $0$). But then again, how can one find this by making use of eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose that v is an eigenvector for your map, and let w be any other vector such that {v,w} is a basis. How is the matrix of your map with respect to that basis?

Comment: Muchas gracias profesor. Lo saluda un estudiante de la UNC, FAMAF.

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$